# How to set frame of UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, xcode4.2

There's UIButton, button1 for example. I want to set its frame in the code.
I tried `button1.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,50,50);` but I've seen no effect. And I try to output the width in an alert:
`alert.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", button1.frame.size.width]`, and the value is 0.
I don't know why.

Comment: What about NSLog(@"%@", button1); (you can use NSLog instead of displaying alerts). What does that output? It may be that your button1 is nil.

Comment: Are you sure button1 is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UIButton` is most probably not connected in the Interface Builder if it's an outlet or you haven't added it as a subview if you've created it programmatically. Also a small tip. Use `NSStringFromCGRect()` to see your element's frame parameter in detail.

Comment: I'm sorry for that I put the release to the viewdidload but not viewdidunload, which results in the problem. Thanks for your answer very much.